# on-premises azure devops build agent gets 403 error - other builds in different projects work fine

Tags: azure-devops

I have a new project set up in Azure Dev Ops using the same on-premises build pool as all my other projects. This also fails with a Hosted Build Agent.

However the build from this pipeline fails when publishing to our Azure DevOps package feed:

Response status code does not indicate success:

> 403 (Forbidden - User '2ed245a3-1b32-42a2-ab9d-dfaad036294e' lacks
>   permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'.
>   (DevOps Activity ID: B36E439D-1022-42DC-A396-5D2896FB3882)

I don't know what to do about this - I've done nothing different to what I usually do when creating this project, so it looks like some backend wiring up within DevOps hasn't successfully completed. I don't really want to delete this project and re-create it as I've migrated a lot of source code from a prior VSTVC repository in a different project into a git repository in this one.

I've checked the pipeline build job authorization scope - this is set to "project collection" (same as all my other build pipelines in the other projects that all work fine.

I'm using the pipeline step NuGet version 2, Target feed location "This organisation/collection" and selected the correct target feed.

Assuming something has gone wrong I don't know how to fix the permissions in the project to ensure this step works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check that the Hosted Build Agent has the correct permissions to write to disk. Check to see what account it is running as.

Comment: This fails with both the hosted build agent and the on-premise build agents we have, I don't think this is an issue specific to the type of build agent

Comment: Ok, just thinking out loud. I had a similar issue with an AWS agent. Different tech but I thought I'd make the suggestion!

Comment: Does your agent service account have contributor access to the feed?

Comment: Hi, is there good news for trying to assign the role to Build service account? Does this could help for solve the error? Feel to leave comment if still has any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error ID showed in your question, I check the corresponding logs from our backend with these ID.

To solve the issue your are facing, please go **Feed** - open **Feed Setting**.

[image]

Change to **Permissions** tab and click on **Add users/groups**. Then add your build service account `reco****tions Build Service(bibl***group)`, and assign it `Contributor` or `Owner` role.

[image]

---

For the error message you are facing, its `UserId` represents your build service account `reco****tions Build Service(bibl***group)`, which is one **build-in** service account for **Pipeline**. You could find it under your `[bibl***group]\Security Service group`. And the `Activity ID` shows "you" are forbidden to access the feed.

In fact, when you running some pipeline, the execution of all external operations of the pipeline (*including some APIs, restore packages from feed and etc*) is completed by **Service Account**. So, you need to assign the corresponding permission to Service Account based on the specific action in pipeline.

Comment: This fixed the issue but since I haven't had to do this for the other 40 or so projects in our account, I'm guessing this is a one-off? Is there a better way then explicitly adding the rec****tions build service account to the feed? Shouldn't this account be added automatically to the Project Collection Build Service group (or something)?

Comment: @GrahamB The reco***tions is your project name, so this service account can only be available for this specified project. See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines) . Since you have more than 40 projects, I suggest you could change your builds as run in collection level. At this time, its build service account would be Project collection build service which default role is a Contributor for feed.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem some, i fixed it adding the permission in my feed to allow project-scope-builds.

You have to go to Artifacts-->Feed settings (gear on righ-up)-->Permissions tab

[image]

Click on "allow project-scope-builds", this gonna let you to add packages to your feed fixing the issue.

I hope can help you, cheers!!.